# Método de Newton-Raphson junto com Horner

Tags: python, método

Estou tendo problemas para implementar o método de Horner para diminuir o custo computacional dos cálculos de polinômios e, feito isso, usar o método de Newton para achar a raiz do polinômio

No código, b armazenaria o valor do polinômio e c o valor da derivada

```
n=len(a)-1
print("k\ta\tx\tpx")
for k in range (1, iterMax):
    b=a[n] 
    c=0
    for i in range (n-1,1):
        c=b-(x*c)
        b=(x*b)+a[i]
    b=x*b+a[0]
    if (b<epsilon and b>-epsilon):
        print ("raiz encontrada: ")
        print (x)
        return (0, x)
    x=x-(b/c)   
print("erro. Maximo de interações atingido") 
return (1, x)
```

Ao aplicar o método de Newton (x=x-(b/c)), acusa erro dizendo que estou dividindo por zero, mas não entendo porque.

Chamada da função:

```
a = [3, -9, 0, 1]
x0 = 0.5
epsilon = 0.0001
maxIter = 20
(houveErro, raiz) = newton_poli(a, x0, epsilon, maxIter)
```

Obs: pelo que eu entendi, a lista a armazena os coeficientes de trás pra frente, ou seja, 3 é o termo independente e 1 é o termo que multiplica x³

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no  seu segundo `for`. Você está tentando fazer um loop decrementando e o loop nunca está sendo executado, logo c não tem o seu valor atualizado. Para isso funcionar você precisa adicionar o terceiro parâmetro na função range, logo seu loop ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
for i in range (n-1,1,-1):
```